# Линия соединяющая два блока

Tags: html, javascript

Есть блоки, они могу перетаскиваться в любое место экрана, всего их два вида. Каким образом можно "соединить" два блока разного вида прямой линией, каким образом его лучше рисовать, желательно не canvas.

Comment: Оформляйте в ответы что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не `canvas`, то почему бы не `svg`? Положить большой svg под, или поверх контента, и рисовать в нем линию.

```
<svg height="1080" width="960">
  <line x1="34" y1="56" x2="789" y2="678" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```